# Differing behavior of <Super>+Tab

Tags: release-freya, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (e.g. <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) key combination sometimes works like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> meaning it toggles between windows of the current workspace, but sometimes it toggles between active workspaces.

Why is that?

Comment: Need more context here—when are you getting one instead of the other?

Comment: Lately, it always works like Alt+Tab.

Comment: What is the context of when it works with the other? How long has it been? What do you remember about it? Etc. Is it just that you've switched to Loki?

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. Nowadays it works exactly like Alt+Tab. It has been so for pretty long now, probably since right after I installed Freya. And no, I have not switched to Loki.